# The options [useFindAndModify] is not supported

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongodb-4.0.10 and mongoose-5.2.10

Added `useFindAndModify: false` to the mongoose configuration to avoid warnings like:

> DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and
>   `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to
>   false are deprecated.
>
> DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use
>   findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.

But now 'the options [useFindAndModify] is not supported' is coming on running the app.

Comment: Where are you setting the `useFindAndModify : false`. It should be either at the global `mongoose` level  `mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);` or can be passed to connection `mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });`

Comment: @ambianBeing I am passing the option inside mongoose.connect.

Answer (score 11):

For others who are facing this issue, `useFindAnyModify` is not supported if you are using mongoose version 6+.

To solve this either we can remove `useFindAnyModify` or downgrade mongoose version to use v5+.

Comment: Just adding a reference that supports this answer, from the official documentation for mongoose version 6+ https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

Answer (score 1):

First, update mongoose to ^latest (`5.8.X`) version.

Then rewrite you code and try to use it like this

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${login}:${password}@${hostname}/${auth_db}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    retryWrites: true,
    w: "majority",
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Also, according to `mongoose` [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) on `findOneAndUpdate` you could use `findOne` and update docs via triggering `.save` on result.